# Adding local script files to EJS views

Tags: node.js, express, ejs

I've got a Node/Express/EJS app. It's got a folder for views and another for client files. The latter has another folder for javascript, where I have a file called frontend.js.

I'd like to load jQuery and the frontend.js file in this view.

The standard script tags don't work.

```
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../client/js/frontend.js"></script>
```

jQuery loads, frontend.js throws a 404 error.

Is there a special way of doing this that I'm not aware of?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

in your `app.js` file add this :

```
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client')))
```

change the second script tag to :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/js/frontend.js"></script>
```

I'm assuming that your `app.js` file and `client` folder are in the same folder.

Comment: I use the function in frontend.js <% myfunc("strParam") %> but no luck :(

Comment: No need for the path.join