# Loading third party scripts such src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js" into Nodejs application

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, here-api, here-maps-rest

I am trying to integrate Here maps into my Nodejs website. What I want to do is create a map object as show below inside my app.js file.

```
var map = new H.Map(
          document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
          maptypes.normal.map,
          {
              zoom: 10,
              center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
          });
```

Then I want to pass this map object to my ejs file to display. But I am not able to figure how to load the  below scripts into my application. These files are the scripts provided by Here maps, which needs to be loaded for creating the map object.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
             type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
             type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

If I try to load these files into my ejs files I get an error stating **H is not defined**. Can someone please tell me how to load these scripts in my application so I have access for new H.map(...). And how do I make these variables available in my ejs file

> Long Story Short I want to add the following code in to my nodejs application, separating the code inside the script tag in a js file and HTML part into a EJS file

```html
<html>
  <head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, width=device-width" />
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-core.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  <script src="http://js.api.here.com/v3/3.0/mapsjs-service.js"
  type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
  <div style="width: 640px; height: 480px" id="mapContainer"></div>
  <script>
    // Initialize the platform object:
    var platform = new H.service.Platform({
    'app_id': '{YOUR_APP_ID}',
    'app_code': '{YOUR_APP_CODE}'
    });

    // Obtain the default map types from the platform object
    var maptypes = platform.createDefaultLayers();

    // Instantiate (and display) a map object:
    var map = new H.Map(
    document.getElementById('mapContainer'),
    maptypes.normal.map,
    {
      zoom: 10,
      center: { lng: 13.4, lat: 52.51 }
    });
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are using EJS, you might want to check this out:
[How to include external .js file to ejs Node template page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47001537/how-to-include-external-js-file-to-ejs-node-template-page)

In short, the script in EJS runs on server side before the page is send to the client.

To use the the third party scripts, try installing them on your server side.

```
npm i here-js-api
```

And then load the them into your script:
[Adding local script files to EJS views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42647728/adding-local-script-files-to-ejs-views)